# how to implement anti phishing mechanisn for a web application

Tags: security, phishing

we have internal portal which we will use for configuration.  How to implement anti phishing mechanism 
1.which mechanism to use
2.how to use
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phishing protection are not only at your application level but also by making your users aware of what a phishing is. Even top-noch banks are vulnerable to phishing attacks.

I would suggest you:

- Aware your users by adding a note on what is phishing within your application
- Implement a SSL Certificate to improve the protection on phishing https://www.liquidweb.com/blog/index.php/secure-your-website-ssl-certificates-with-phishing-protection/ (just one more measure, it doesn't guarantee to be bulletproof)

A mechanism i've seen in a few banks is :

- Make the user insert his username
- Show an image only know by him that user chose previously at registrarion.
- Make the user accept that he/she choose that image previously
- Make the user insert his password

This way if a user is a victim of a phishing attack, the attacker must know not just his username but also the image that the user choose.

Also in case the user doesn't exists you should set up a fake image so you prevent a user enumeration attack.

Comment: Good answer, but I would amend that to "the attacker must know his username" because once the username is known the image can be determined so this will not protect against spear phishing. Also to stop user enumeration you must show the same image for the same username each time - otherwise it will be known that the user does not exist if it changes on each attempt.